# Working on a way to show current Android phone location in Google Maps

Tags: android, api, google-maps

Looking for a little bit of help structuring my problem.

I will be traveling with friends to a party weekend and we are plotting locations of places to visit and see on a shared Google map with custom layers.

My thought is that I could add real-time location layers for each attendee, based on the lat/long of those with Android phones.

I'm trying to figure at the moment the elements of the code that I will need and asking the community for help structuring the design.

So far:

1. Working on a way to broadcast the current lat/long of the Android phone through an API
2. Determining the best way to import the returns (lat/long) from the API as a layer into Google Maps (thinking KML, but there may be a better solution with GPX or text files)
3. Once I finish 1 and 2, will write the code to accomplish the process and load to Google Maps

Any guidance is very much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to develop everything of this sort when Google has already provided us with the ***My Map*** app. This app is available in Play Sore for Google as well as the App Store for Apple. So all your friends whether an Android or iPhone user can install this app on their phone.

With this app you all can customize the map as per the needs and share inside the group. This app explicitly serves the purpose for the vacation planning when a group is involved.

Take a look on the [Google Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.m4b&hl=en) and the [App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/my-maps/id620245309?mt=8) to explore and download.

Comment: My Map is great but I cannot figure out how to share my current GPS location with others on the map. I can see myself on my My Map but others cannot.